# Is this result true for $|x|,|y| \le 2$ and $|x|\neq |y|$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, solution-verification

Given $|x|, |y|\le 2$ , where $x,y$ are real numbers and $x|\neq |y|$, is the following true?

$|x-y| \ge \frac 1{|x+y|} $ if and only if $|x-y|\ge \frac 1{|x|+|y|}$.

My intution says **No**.

First of all , $|x| \neq |y|$ implies $x\neq y,-y$ and so $|x+y||x-y| \neq 0$

Certainly , the **if** part is true i.e

Let $|x-y| \ge \frac 1{|x+y|} $ hold.

Then using $|x+y| \le |x|+|y|$,  we have

$|x-y| \ge \frac 1{|x+y|} \ge 
\frac 1{|x|+|y|} $

I think there must $x,y$ such that

$\frac 1{|x+y|} \gt |x-y| \ge \frac 1{|x|+|y|}$ , with the strict inequality there.

First of all, I list out when is the converse implication actually true.

$(1)$ When $xy\gt 0$( i.e they are of same sign), then

$|x+y|=|x|+|y|$

So the converse results hold true.

$(2)$ If $xy=0$ , then one of $x$ or $y$ is $0$ (both can't be zero together) , then also it is easy to see the converse result holds.

Lastly,  $xy \lt 0$ .Well, since the condition is symmetric in $x$ and $y$, we may assume without loss of generality , $-2\le y \lt 0 \lt x\le 2$

This is the interesting case at which I am stuck at and hope to find a desired example but somehow I am not getting what I wanted.

Is the converse actually true? Please help me complete this.

Thanks for your time and attention.

Comment: take $x \to +1$ and $y \to -1$ then $|x+y| \to 0+$ and $|x|+|y| \to 2$, both inequality break down

Comment: Thanks for the helpful insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just take x=1 and y=-0.5 .